# Title text for voting in election

Tags: bug, voting, election

Although this is tagged as [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), I think it is more of an oversight.

[image]

The election nominations aren't questions. Besides, how do they "show research effort" and be "useful and clear"? Something more like "Vote for this candidate" and "Vote against this candidate" would be more clear.